# How to add arrows in matTooltip?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, tooltip

I'm trying to add arrows on matTooltip, there is any way to add arrows on matTooltip.

```html
<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="Info about the action"
        aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">   
        Action 
</button>
```

Comment: Yes! as we see in bootstrap tooltip!

Comment: Arrow? What kind of arrow? What do you mean by "arrows"?

Comment: I'm talking about direction arrows of tooltip! below is example of bootstrap tooltip with arrows, i want to add in matooltip.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

Comment: It there a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override material styles. and add before/after pseudo-element as arrow. For example if you need to style a tooltip with left border and arrow just do something like that

```
.mat-tooltip {
    // to make possible place arrow pseudo element outside tooltip with absolute positioning
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    &.right {
        border-left: 6px solid red;
        margin-left: 5px;
        &::before {
            position: absolute;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: red;
            clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 50%, 50% 100%);
            left: -12px;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `right` we need to use `.mat-tooltip-panel-below` without dependent of `.mat-tooltip`. I want to give tranistion effect to arrow along with tooltop. Any idea how to do it ? right now if I remove my cursor the arrow hide late.

Answer (score 1):

Angular material v16

I did like this

```
.mat-mdc-tooltip::before {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    rotate: 45deg;
    right: 50% !important;
    left: auto !important;
    transform: translate(4px, -4px);
}

.mat-mdc-tooltip-panel-above .mat-mdc-tooltip::before {
    top: auto;
    bottom: -6px !important;
}

.mat-mdc-tooltip-panel-below .mat-mdc-tooltip::before {
    top: -6px !important;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

Adjust values to match with your design

Answer (score -1):

Following the usage of Material Design, arrows are not included in angular tooltip component. Here you could take a look what you can do and not to do with tooltips https://material.io/components/tooltips/

Comment: I gotta say, I don't think that was a good decision on the part of the Material Design folks.